# Phonegapp app login through safari nor working correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, html, cordova

I have a app built in html 5 and published through phonegap, i have built in cordova and InAppbrowsing which allows to open a external link in safari and then return to app when i am done with the link. The problem i am having is that when i click on the link it opens in safari perfectly, but the i login to say the backend of my site and what happens is if i click on any of the links in the backend of my site while logged in it boots me back out to the login page. I have tried logging in through safari outside of the app and it works fine but if use it inside the app i get the problem above, can anyone help here?

Comment: Please post any screenshots or logs that you may have.  It is hard to understand the problem without these.